# How to run an EventMachine application on your own production server?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I have just written my first EventMachine application. In development, to start the server, all I do is:

```
ruby myapp.rb
```

Which runs my application until I kill it with control+C. In production, this doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

How would I go about running this on my production server?

Answer (score 1):

Check out daemons: http://daemons.rubyforge.org/ - a simple gem written for precisely this use case.

Answer (score 0):

At PostRank we always used [God](http://god.rubyforge.org/) to start/restart our production EventMachine APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have a completely external process handling my daemons rather than using something like the daemons library but that's a personnal preference.

You have many solutions out there, here those I know of, all of them will restart your application when it crash more or les quickly and some offer a management interface whether it is a cli or a web interface:

- supervisord (http://supervisord.org/): he one I prefer so far
- daemontools (http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html): works well but can be anoying to configure
- god as mentionned (http://god.rubyforge.org/): Never used it most for this horrible and cryptic config file syntax

And the last one is whatever comes with your linux distrib, init can run an application and restart it when it dies, you have neary no control over it but it can do the job.
You can type "man inittab" to learn more.